# SSH connect failed - ssh: Could not resolve hostname server: Name or service not known

Tags: ssh

Any ideas why ssh Could not resolve?

My private key is in this location:
/home/eago/.ssh

and config looks like this

```
Host my-host.com
HostName my-host.com
Port 22
IdentityFile /home/eago/.ssh/id_rsa
```

This is what i get:

```
$ ssh -vT gitolite@psc-app-1.superhosting.cz:dalnice_android
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.8, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/eago/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
ssh: Could not resolve hostname psc-app-1.superhosting.cz:dalnice_android: Name or service not known
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
ssh -vT gitolite@psc-app-1.superhosting.cz
```

You do not need to add a directory name in this case `dalnice_android`